# Unable to generate a URL for the named route "sg_calendar_update_xhr_event"

Tags: symfony, calendar, bundle

I have installed recently **SgCalendarBundle,** in Symfony, and first of all I create the path to sg_calendar:

```
//src MyBundle/config/routing.yml
sg_calendar:
    pattern: /calendar
    defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:index }
```

But when I execute my page with the tag

```
<a class="brand" href="{{ path('sg_calendar') }}">SgCalendarBundle</a>
```

I get the following error in symfony: `Unable to generate a URL for the named route "sg_calendar_update_xhr_event" as such route does not exist.
500 Internal Server Error - RouteNotFoundException`.

Comment: Did you import `MyBundle/config/routing.yml` in `app/config/routing.yml`?

Comment: Yes I do, because the path follows to the CalendarController but it doesn't work...

Comment: did you define sg_calendar_update_xhr_event somewhere ?

Comment: mmm no... Where can I define it?

Comment: Have you add the bundle in your AppKernel, and had the cache cleared ?

Comment: Yes I have, I have definded also other route for create the form: 

`sg_calendar_create_calendar:
     pattern: /calendar
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:post }` 
the calendar exists in my db, but I can't display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get the solution myself.
You just need to route all the routes by your own way:

```
   //app/config/routing.yml

 sg_calendar:
    path: /calendar
    defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:index }

sg_calendar_create_event:
     path: /calendar/event/new
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Event:new }

sg_calendar_create_calendar:
     path: /calendar/create
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:get }

sg_calendar_update_xhr_event:
     path: /calendar/event/update
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Event:update }

sg_calendar_new_calendar:
     path: /calendar/new
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:new }

sg_calendar_new_event:
     path: /calendar/event/new
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Event:new }

sg_calendar_get_calendar:
     path: /calendar/{id}/show
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:get }

sg_calendar_edit_calendar:
     path: /calendar/{id}/edit
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:edit }

sg_calendar_remove_calendar:
     path: /calendar/{id}/remove
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:remove }

sg_calendar_get_xhr_events:
     path: /calendar/event/{id}/show
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Event:get }

sg_calendar_update_calendar:
     path: /calendar/{id}/update
     defaults: { _controller: SgCalendarBundle:Calendar:update }
```

Answer (score 3):

Routes by annotations need to be imported into routing.yml:

```
# app/config/routing.yml

# SgRruleBundle
sg_rrule:
    resource: "@SgRruleBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

# SgCalendarBundle
sg_calendar:
    resource: "@SgCalendarBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

This documentation issue was fixed: https://github.com/stwe/CalendarBundle/issues/1